# Выбор бесплатной CMS для создания интернет-магазина

Tags: cms, интернет-магазин

Подскажите, пожалуйста, бесплатную CMS, которую лучше всего подойдет для создания интернет-магазина. Какую CMS используете Вы?

Comment: Могу сказать, что **нельзя** - zen cart. Было нес-ко заказов и литры кровавых слез. А вообще опишите нужный функционал (каталог это или таки магазин, наличие корзины, профилей доставки, интеграция с платежками etc).

Comment: > Какую CMS используете Вы?

Только ту, которую своими руками написал. Не существует в природе такой CMS, которой я бы больше доверял, чем своей, а уж о бесплатной - я вообще молчу.

Comment: А какие мнения по поводу Magento и PrestaShop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Magento

громоздкая

> PrestaShop

тоже не нравится.

я сторонник, как писал [@Deonis](/users/4058/deonis) своего велосипеда. Тем более с годами свой велосипед становится универсальным "оружием" т.к. во всех системах много всего, чего порой никогда и не требуется. Обычный инет магазин(каталог товаров, корзина, заказ) пишется за 1-3 дня. А вот административка бывает очень сложной. Сейчас работаю в инет-магазине, и админка это мощный инструмент для обработки заказов, рассылок смс и мыл, расчетов скидок, приема ответов от многих сервисов, слежение за посылками через почту россии и прочее.

А сам сайт до безумия прост.

Так что из вышеперечисленных ЦМС ничего не посоветую.

Answer (score 3):

Drupal +  ubercart. Но все же советую задуматься над платными движками

Comment: платные движки, порой, еще хуже бесплатных!

Answer (score 0):

не соглашусь, что бесплатные движки — слезы. Многие да, но мне в последнее время понравился  [DotPlant2](https://github.com/devgroup-ru/dotplant2) на  Yii2, довольно толковый сделали и код не такой, что кровавыми слезами рыдать хочется.